spectral theory of pseudo-differential operators of class $S^m$
I would be very grateful if you could give me the titles of books that deal with the spectral theory of pseudo-differential operators of class  $S^m$
Thank you very much.

A suggestion: add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

ok. Thank you for your help
